# Merge vector and initializer_list in initialization of vector<vector<T>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list

Say I am initialization a `vector<vector<string>>` like so:

```
vector<vector<string>> v;
v = {{
    {"a", "b", "c"},
    {"aa", "bb"},
    {"xyz", "yzx", "zxy"},
    {}
}};
```

Now suppose I want to append an already existing `vector<string>` to some of `v`'s elements. Like so:

```
vector<string> suffix {{"1", "2", "3"}};
vector<vector<string>> v;
v = {{
    {"a", "b", "c"} + suffix,
    {"aa", "bb"},
    {"xyz", "yzx", "zxy"} + suffix,
    {}
}};
```

That syntax obviously doesn't work because `operator+` is not defined in such a way.

I understand that it's possible to construct `v` the first way and then write

```
vector<int> indices = {0, 2};
for(int i: indices)
   v[i].insert(v[i].end(), suffix.begin(), suffix.end());
```

But this is not convenient because I may have several `suffix` vectors that are attached to arbitrary `v[i]`. I want the `suffix` to be together with the initialization of the `v[i]` so it makes sense and I don't have to shift indices if I add/remove elements from `v`'s initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a helper function that does the appending.

```
vector<string> appendStrings(vector<string>&& s1, vector<string> const& s2)
{
   s1.insert(s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
   return s1;
}
```

And use it to initialize the variable.

```
vector<string> suffix {{"1", "2", "3"}};
vector<vector<string>> v = {{
    appendStrings({"a", "b", "c"}, suffix),
    {"aa", "bb"},
    appendStrings({"xyz", "yzx", "zxy"}, suffix),
    {}
}};
```

**Update**

A more efficient implementation of `appendStrings` (Thanks to @Yakk):

```
vector<string> appendStrings(initializer_list<char const*>&& s1,
                             vector<string> const& s2)
{
   vector<string> ret.
   ret.reserve(s1.size() + s2.size());
   for (auto item : s1 ) {
      ret.emplace_back(item);
   }
   ret.insert(ret.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end() );
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: If `s1` is an initializer list, avoid an allocation.  If you `move` return, avoid another.

Comment: @Yakk, I think I understand the `move` return part but I have no idea what you mean by the first part of your comment.

Comment: Change `vector<string>&&` to `std::initializer_list<const char*>` (or `T`).  Create a `vector` within that `reserves` enough for said list and 2nd `vector`, then load it up, and return.  Get 1 memory allocation, plus 1 per `std::string` allocated, instead of your ... 3? plus 2 per `std::string` (`move` drops it to 2+1).  Just microoptimization.

Comment: @Yakk The move return seems redundant to me. NRVO will already take care of it.

Comment: Now the return is redundant (and costs NRVO), originally it was retur ing an rvakue reference parameter.